# What does the “MISSING” directive mean in a dircolors file?

Tags: shell, coreutils

I ran `dircolors --print-database` to show the default `dircolors` configuration and it included these lines (reformatted for clarity):

```
# symlink to nonexistent file, or non-stat'able file ...
ORPHAN 40;31;01

# ... and the files they point to
MISSING 00
```

I understand how a symlink can point to a nonexistent file. But how does it make sense to specify the color of the pointed-to file, since such a file can’t exist in the first place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the `-l` option, `ls` displays the target of each symbolic link. If you specify a style for `MISSING` then this will be used to display the target of a broken link. (If you don’t specify a style, or use the default `00`, then the target will be displayed with the same style as is used for the link name itself.)